# How to deserialize JSON from Postgres row_to_json() back to Table record in Jooq?

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I'm trying to get a Jooq Table record from json produced with postgres row_to_json().

I have a Table called InventoryItem in Postgres with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE "InventoryItem" (
  "id" BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  "price_per_100_units" double precision,
  "weight_in_kilograms" double precision,
  "inventory_count" integer,
  "expected_value" double precision,
  "description" text
);
```

When I use row_to_json() in Postgres to create a Json for a single row from this table, I get:

```
{
  "id": 6,
  "price_per_100_units": null,
  "weight_in_kilograms": null,
  "inventory_count": null,
  "expected_value": 142,
  "description": null
}
```

I couldn't find a way to take the above Json and convert it into an instance of Jooq InventoryItemRecord.

I tried to use Jooq's import Json functionality, but that only works for the Json format produced from Jooq export to Json. It doesn't work
with row_to_json() output.

As a last resort, I could write a Pojo to which I deserialize the above json and then create JooqRecord from this pojo, but this seems like a lot of work
for multiple tables.

How does one convert row_to_json() output to a Jooq TableRecord?

Comment: See [JSON Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-json.html) `json_populate_...` and `json_to_,,,`.

Comment: @Belayer Thanks for your comment, it set me in the direction to my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DSLContext::fetchFromJSON`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#fetchFromJSON(java.lang.String)) to load any jOOQ supported JSON format into a jOOQ [`Result`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Result.html), e.g.

```java
Object v = ctx.fetchValue(
    "select row_to_json(x) from inventory_item as x where id = 1");
InventoryItemRecord record = ctx.fetchFromJSON("[" + v + "]")
                                .into(INVENTORY_ITEM)
                                .get(0);
```

You're probably looking for this convenience feature, which isn't available yet in jOOQ 3.17:

- [#8016](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/8016) Add API to load individual records from XML, JSON, CSV, etc.

But the above is almost equivalent, except that you have to:

- Wrap your JSON object in a JSON array, manually
- Map your generic `Record` containing the JSON data into an `InventoryItemRecord` manually.

Comment: your solution solved my problem. I wanted to add this for anyone else running into this problem:
I used this bit of config while outputting json from jooq:

`            JSONFormat jsonFormat = new JSONFormat().header(false).recordFormat(JSONFormat.RecordFormat.OBJECT);
`

The RecordFormat.OBJECT changed the output format from array to object and made it easy.

Comment: @J.Cool: You can also add an answer here on Stack Overflow, to increase visibility for anyone else. I think it will certainly be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Adding my comment as a full answer to be clear.
Jooq by default seems to use the array format when exporting a record to json. If you're trying to interface postgres `row_to_json()`, you need to tell Jooq to use Json object format when exporting to json.

I was able to achieve this by:

```
JSONFormat jsonFormat = new
JSONFormat().header(false).recordFormat(JSONFormat.RecordFormat.OBJECT);
```

Specifying `RecordFormat.OBJECT` does the trick.